# How do I write a proper statement to prove that I'm using the Intermediate value theorem correctly

Tags: limits, functions

> $f(x)= \displaystyle x^3-\frac{2x^2}{15}$

> $g(x)= \displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{15}$

Use intermediate value theorem to show that they have at least 3 intersections in the interval $[-1,1]$

Let $h(x)=\displaystyle x^3-\frac{2x^2}{15} - \frac{\sin x}{15}=0$

Let $a=-0.5$, $b=0.7$

Now, I evaluate $h(-1)$, $h(1)$, $h(-0.5)$, $h(0.7)$

$h(-1) = -1.077 (<0)$

$h(1) = 0.8105 (>0)$

$h(0.7) = 0.2347 (>0)$

$h(-0.5) = -0.1264 (<0)$

From this, I need to pick intervals of $< 0 , $ and $>0$, which is $[-1,1], [-1,0.7], [-0.5,1]$

Now, I conclude, by applying IVT on $h(x)$ on 3 intervals, we can conclude that $f(c_1)=0$ for some $c_1 \in (-1,1)$ $f(c_2)=0$ for some $c_2 \in (-1,0.7), $ and $f(c_3)=0$ for some $c_3 \in (-0.5,1)$. This proves that $h(x)$ have 3 intersections on $[-1,1]$

My statement is unclear, how do I change it to make it clearer? Also, why do I need to pick intervals of $<0$ and $>0$.

Comment: The question asks you to find three distinct intersections. Since your intervals overlap you have no basis to conclude that $c_{1}\ne c_{2} \ne c_{3}$ i.e. that you have found three distinct intersections. Indeed, $0$ is in all of your intervals.  What you must do is to find three disjoint intervals where $h$ changes sign, this will guarantee three distinct intersections by the IVT.

Answer (score 1):

IVT: For any function $f$ that is continuous in a closed interval $[a,b]$, there exists a c for some f(c).

In order to apply intermediate value theorem, you need to explain that:

1. The interval $[a,b]$ is a subset of the domain of the function(s)
2. The functions are continuous in the interval $[a,b]$

So I would first explain that the functions f and g are both defined in the interval $[a,b]$ $(i.e [a,b] \subseteq D_f,[a,b] \subseteq D_g)$ and that they are continuous functions over its domain (since f is an algebraic function and g is a trig function)

Next I will choose an interval such that $f(x)>g(x)$ for some $x$ and $f(x)<g(x)$ for some $x$, such that $x \in [a,b]$ and show by intermediate value theorem that there exist a c such that $f(x)=g(x)$  (Repeat 3 times)

Note: When you repeat different examples, you must show that the points are distict, i.e $c_1 \not=c_2 \not =c_3$ as mentioned by @Manifoldski

Tip: You can input functions $f$ and $g$ into Geogebra can choose nice intervals from there.